# Bundle ID not appearing in the drop down in iTunes Connect Add New Application

Tags: iphone

This morning we are not able to see the newly added bundle ids in the drop when we attempt to add a new app!

Is there a limit on the number of bundle id's one developer account can create? Anyone else facing this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Yup, me too. Although others I created before showed up. Let's wait.

I'd assume the following:

- Apple does not synchronize their databases in real time but every x hours or days.
- Someone has to review the App IDs manually (unlikely).
- They have a real database problem over there. But with the large number of Developers, I doubt they'd leave such a heavy bug in there.

As a sidenote: SO is probably the wrong place for such questions. The Apple Discussion Forums are much better suited for that.

Comment: Now that it has been a year... did waiting work? Or still waiting?

Comment: Seems to have been fixed a good while ago. App IDs normally appear instantly or after a short period. So, if in doubt, just wait.

Comment: I'm still seeing this issue. Some discussion at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4192326?start=30&tstart=0 and https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5494721 but didn't help me.

Comment: after 4.5 years of this post, the issue still persists.

Comment: I have only problems with Apple...they should change the motto to "It just does NOT work".

Comment: 2019 and... you guessed it

Comment: October 2019, I have the same issue

Comment: I have the same issue here too

Comment: I have the same problem yesterday and today.

Comment: 2020, same problem